# Asus Zenfone 8z OEM Unlocking option is missing

Tags: android, custom-rom, asus

I want to install a custom ROM on my Asus Zenfone 8z but the "OEM Unlocking" is missing in the developer options. I went through a lot searching for a solution but I wasn't able to find any. Resulting which, I am here to ask some experts. I have heard that this issue is also there on some of the Samsung devices. Can anyone guide me how I can flash a custom ROM and OS on my device OR get the the OEM Unlocking option in the Developer Options?

Comment: Consider [android.se] for this question -- Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing programs.